# Flash to AIR to Testflight for android and iOS. How do I implement the Testflight SDK?

Tags: flash, air, testflight

I wonder if you guys could possibly point me in the right direction here? (Thank you so much if you can!)

I am currently working on a mobile(android/iOS) app using Flash, publishing with AIR and wanting to test in Testflight. Great, I thought! Well not for the want of trying and stabbing and heads banged on desks, this is where I am floundering.

Can anyone shed some light on how to implement the Testflight SDK whilst publishing with Adobe AIR? (I have read as much as I can find on this, to no avail. Maybe I can't see the forest for the trees...)

Is this really a viable workflow? The app is animation and illustration heavy, hence the reliance on Flash, though would be interested to hear your thoughts on possible alternate approaches.

Thanks for any help and thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an AIR Native Extension (commonly referred to as an ANE) to fully use the Testflight SDK. There is one developed by Adobe, but I don't believe it was ever updated for the 2.0 SDK. A quick search turned up [this ANE for iOS](https://github.com/thejustinwalsh/TestFlightANE), but it does not support Android from the looks of it. You'll have to search for one that does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Alex with the Burstly team. We have an AIR Native Extension for SkyRocket and TestFlight functionality in a private beta. If you wish, forward your github handle to alex-at-burstly.com and I'll be able to grant you access to this.

- Alex

Answer (score 0):

Josh Janusch is right about the ANE, and it works fine. But TestFlight is now demanding you use version 3 of their SDK by march 23, I haven't found any ANE's that support this.